# Writing Spark SQL query on data without header or schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a generic script that can run SQL queries on a file that doesn't have a header or pre-defined schema. For example, a file could look like:

```
Bob,32
Alice, 24
Jane,65
Doug,33
Peter,19
```

And the SQL query might be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ??) 
FROM temp_table
WHERE ?? > 32
```

I am wondering what to put in the `??`.

Comment: can't you declare a 'custom schema' when reading the file ?

Comment: dataframe/dataset without schema is not possible

Answer (score 2):

you can define 'custom schema' while reading like

```
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("field1", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("field2", IntegerType, true) :: Nil
) 

val df = spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("sep", ",")
    .option("header", "false")
    .schema(schema)
    .load("examples/src/main/resources/people.csv")
```

also you can ignore the schema part that would end-up in default names (not-preferred)

```
 val df = spark.read.format("csv")
     .option("sep", ",")
     .option("header", "false")
     .load("examples/src/main/resources/people.csv")

+-----+-----+
|  _c0|  _c1|
+-----+-----+
|  Bob|  32 |  
|  .. | ... |  
+-----+-----+
```

with that you can fill the column names in your spark-sql.

Comment: To be completely generic I can’t use schema.

Answer (score 0):

It seems default schema has column names `_c0`, `_c1` etc.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("test.txt")

scala> df.printSchema
root
  |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
  |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
```

In Spark 2.0,

```
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")
  spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT _c1) FROM temp_table WHERE cast(_c1 as int) > 32")
```